# Use QBFC from a desktop application to interface to Quickbooks online

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbfc

We have a windows desktop based application that interfaces to Quickbooks Pro desktop using QBFC.

It creates a QBSessionManager, adds message sets to it, performs the requests, and parses the responses.

Is it possible to use this existing QBFC based interface from the desktop application to update Quickbooks online instead?  Obviously there would be some changes since we're not loading a local company file, but can we leverage this code to also talk to Quickbooks online?

Perhaps by installing a shim that transports the XML to the online version?
Or utilizing the XML generated by QBFC to update QB online?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use this existing QBFC based interface from the desktop application to update Quickbooks online instead?

No.

The issue here is that the XML that you're generating for QBD(desktop) is very different from the XML (or JSON) that QBO(nline) requires.

The *concepts* are the same (there are still customers, and invoices, and payments, etc.) but the actual XML messages are significantly different.

Additionally, the authentication mechanisms (a DCOM handshake vs. OAuth) and transports (COM vs. HTTP/TLS) are significantly different so that you can't really use the QBFC components with QBO.

You will likely get to re-use a lot of your code because the concepts are the same, but the parts you re-use won't be any QBFC or XML bits.

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking. I was hoping maybe they had a drop-in replacement for qbfc that would have the same interface but would it connect to QuickBooks web.

Comment: Unfortunately not. :-(  There's just too much that's different to really make that easily feasible.